# Finding the maximum element of an array using recursion

Tags: c

My Code is this will this find max number from array using recursion but it is not finding biggest Number

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maximum(int ar[], int n)
{

    if (n == 1) {
        return ar[0];

    } else {
        int max = maximum(ar, n-1);
        printf("Largest element : %d\n", max);
        return 5; // return ar[n-1] > max ? ar[n-1] : max;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5] = {5, 23, 28, 7, 1};
    printf("Maximum element of the array is: %d", maximum(array, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you comparing numbers from the array? Hint: You're not.

Comment: Why you commented out `return ar[n-1] > max ? ar[n-1] : max;`?

Comment: You don't need recursion for this, just start out with the first element as your "max" and compare each element with the max. If the element you are comparing is bigger than the previous, then that becomes the max until the end. Use a for-loop starting at 1 and go to the end of the array.

Comment: There is no need for recursion here. [The iterative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547633/finding-sum-min-max-with-array) is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: This program has bugs that we can't fix for you.. for instance, if you add another number to the array and increase `n` to 6, you read beyond the array.

Answer (score 6):

With this particular line

```
return 5; // return ar[n-1] > max ? ar[n-1] : max;
```

in

```
if (n == 1) {
        return ar[0];

    } else {
        int max = maximum(ar, n-1);
        printf("Largest element : %d\n", max);
        return 5; // return ar[n-1] > max ? ar[n-1] : max;
    }
}
```

it will always return 5!

Comment: No, it won't... He is passing 5 as second parameter. And 5 != 1 ! In the end, it will hit n == 1 eventually, that is true!

Comment: there's another small bug.. it will call maximum twice at the end, so that 28 is printed twice... if he comments in that line again

Comment: I think the printf in the maximum function was just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score -4):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int pin[10]={2,4,6,34,56,54,34,23,1,10},i,max,k;

    max=pin[0];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(pin[i]>=max)
        {
            max=pin[i];
            k=i;
        }
    }
    printf("The max number of the array is: %d and it is in  %d position of the array\n",max,k+1);
}
```